# How to auto update the following schema based upon certain condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have `Auction Schema as follows`

```
import { Document, model, Schema } from "mongoose";
import { IProduct } from "./product";
const AuctionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    products: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product" }],
    status: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    duration: { type: Number },
    start: { type: Date },
    end: { type: Date },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export interface IAuction extends Document {
  name: string;
  status?: boolean;
  products: IProduct["_id"][];
  start?: Date;
  end?: Date;
  duration?: number;
}

const Auction = model<IAuction>("Auction", AuctionSchema);

export default Auction;
```

I want to update this auction related field i.e status to false automatically if the field start and end are same

How to do this?

Comment: When do you want to update the status field on save or update?

Comment: when start and end time matches at database automatically without triggering any events

Comment: The database won't spontaneously change the start and end date, it would probably be simplest to have whatever process is setting the dates also set the boolean.

Comment: In addition to Joe answer, you can run pre hooks on mongoose to set the status if you don't want it in the business logic.